# Vue 3 click event is not working on safari

Tags: javascript, vue.js, safari, tailwind-css

I have this table component and I'm facing an issue with the @click event not firing on safari while being working just fine on chrome

```
  <table class="h-full w-full">
    <thead class="sticky top-0 rounded bg-gray-100 shadow-sm">
      <tr class="t-head">
        <th
          v-for="column in visibleCols"
          :key="column.index"
          class="min-w-fit whitespace-nowrap rounded border-r p-3 text-left font-medium text-gray-800 last:border-0"
          @mouseenter="showSortIcon({ column })"
          @mouseleave="hideSortIcon({ column })"
        >
          <div class="flex item-center gap-3">
            <div>{{ column.displayName || "" }}</div>
            <button
              v-if="isSortEnabled && (column as Column).isSortable"
              class="hover:text-indigo-600 transition-opacity duration-300 ease-in-out"
              :class="[
                activeSortColumn.column == column || (sortIconState.column == column && sortIconState.visible)
                  ? 'opacity-100'
                  : 'opacity-0',
              ]"
              @click="onSortIconClicked(column)"
            >
              <i
                class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out"
                :class="[column == activeSortColumn.column && activeSortColumn.isDesc ? 'rotate-180' : 'rotate-0']"
              />
            </button>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody v-if="loading" class="bg-white">
      <tr>
        <td :colspan="visibleCols.length">
          <div class="flex">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-notch m-auto animate-spin text-3xl text-indigo-600"></i>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody v-else-if="data && data.length !== 0 && visibleCols.length !== 0" class="bg-white">
      <tr
        v-for="(row, index) in data"
        :key="index"
        class="border-b last:border-0"
        :class="{ 'cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-100': areRowsClickable }"
        @click="handleRowClick(row)"
      >
        <td
          v-for="cell in visibleCols"
          :key="cell.index"
          class="min-w-fit whitespace-nowrap border-r px-3 py-2 text-left last:border-0"
          :class="cell.class"
        >
          <component :is="cell.component(row, emit)" v-if="!('accessor' in cell) && cell.component !== undefined" />
          <span v-else-if="'accessor' in cell && cell.component === undefined && row[cell.accessor] !== null">
            {{ row[cell.accessor] }}
          </span>
          <component
            :is="cell.component(row[cell.accessor])"
            v-else-if="'accessor' in cell && cell.component !== undefined"
          />
          <span v-else>---</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody v-else class="bg-white">
      <tr>
        <td :colspan="visibleCols.length">
          <slot name="empty-state">
            <div class="flex h-[200px]">
              <span class="m-auto">No data to display</span>
            </div>
          </slot>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Also the tailwind `hover` effect is not showing as well.
I inspected the page and found out the following:

1. When I tried selected the table body with the element selection tool I was not able to.
2. When I selected a row from the elements tab and this checked the hover checkbox the hover effect was rendered successfully.
   I'm using macOS Ventura 13.0 with safari version 16.1

Comment: console isn't has a bug reports ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was the following:
I changed the whole table structure to use divs instead.
I utilized the following Tailwind classes:

1. table
2. table-row
3. table-row-group
4. table-cell

The final result looked something like this

```
<div class="table w-full table-auto" :class="gridCols">
      <!-- HEADER -->
      <div class="sticky top-0 table-row bg-gray-200">
        <div
          v-for="column in visibleCols"
          :key="column.index"
          class="table-cell whitespace-nowrap border-b border-r border-gray-300 p-3 text-left font-medium text-gray-800 last:border-r-0"
          @mouseenter="showSortIcon({ column })"
          @mouseleave="hideSortIcon({ column })"
        >
          <div class="item-center flex gap-3">
            <div>{{ column.displayName || "" }}</div>
            <button
              v-if="isSortEnabled && (column as Column).isSortable"
              class="transition-opacity duration-300 ease-in-out hover:text-indigo-600"
              :class="[
                activeSortColumn.column == column || (sortIconState.column == column && sortIconState.visible)
                  ? 'opacity-100'
                  : 'opacity-0',
              ]"
              @click="onSortIconClicked(column)"
            >
              <i
                class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out"
                :class="[column == activeSortColumn.column && activeSortColumn.isDesc ? 'rotate-180' : 'rotate-0']"
              />
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- BODY -->
      <div v-if="data?.length && !isLoading" class="table-row-group">
        <div
          v-for="row in data"
          :key="row"
          class="table-row border bg-white last:border-0"
          :class="areRowsClickable ? 'cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-100' : ''"
          @click="handleRowClick(row)"
        >
          <div
            v-for="cell in visibleCols"
            :key="cell.displayName"
            class="table-cell whitespace-nowrap border-b border-r px-3 py-2 last:border-r-0"
          >
            <!-- VIRTUAL COLUMN -->
            <component :is="cell.component(row, emit)" v-if="!('accessor' in cell) && cell.component !== undefined" />
            <!-- NORMAL COLUMN -->
            <span v-else-if="'accessor' in cell && cell.component === undefined && row[cell.accessor] !== null">
              {{ row[cell.accessor] }}
            </span>
            <!-- CUSTOM COLUMN -->
            <component
              :is="cell.component(row[cell.accessor])"
              v-else-if="'accessor' in cell && cell.component !== undefined"
            />
            <!-- EMPTY STATE -->
            <span v-else>---</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Don't know why that worked tho! but it seems like Safari doesn't support `<table>` tags to be clickable

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a **button inside a Vue component with a @click handler** set to it, that **only on Safari mobile didn't work**. The reason is completely different, but I write it here in case someone jumps to this question with the same problem I had.

Code that wasn't working:

```html
<template>
  <button class="sticky-button" @click="handleClick"></button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "StickyButton",
  methods: {
    handleClick() {
      const button = this.$el.querySelector('.sticky-button')
      // do something on click
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I found the solution here: https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/70gmf7/vue_click_not_working_on_safari_ios_debug_without/

**I had a css class .sticky-button assigned to the button, which matched the name of the component**. **I changed the class name** to a different one, and I worked like magic!